# Can it be seen as unprofessional to have an avatar as your LinkedIn profile picture?

Tags: professionalism, linkedin, social-media

I have created an identity of myself on the internet, with the following image:

[image: Avatar]

I'm using this image on almost every site I use: Twitter, Gravatar, Stack Overflow, blog, ...

My question is the following: As a CS engineer, can this image be seen as unprofessional by recruiters and shouldn't be used on a site like LinkedIn?

Most of the friends I have have a photo of themselves in a suit, that's why I'm asking this question.

So what can or should I do to avoid an unprofessional image when using an avatar as my profile picture on social networking sites?

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7070/should-i-include-a-picture-on-my-linkedin-profile

Comment: The question you've linked is a bit related, but not the same. Why the downvotes by the way ?

Comment: "avoid asking subjective questions where …

    every answer is equally valid" ([help/dont-ask])

Comment: The question itself and the image are describable in objective terms. I think it is an interesting question a lot of people can relate to, and related to a formal environment where subjectivity is not as important as the knowledge of the codes of this environment. A knowledge that the people on this website can bring.

Comment: I have updated your question to better fit with the site standards.  I do not think your question was poor but this version is more constructive and actionable rather than judgemental.

Comment: I don't have a picture at all.  WHat I look like is immaterial, and if it actually effects the company trying to recruit me then I don't want to work there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An avatar is like a signature or a seal, and you are "signing" your profile with an avatar. Especially since you are using the same "signature" or seal everywhere. That's totally legit, according to me. If your avatar functions as your recognition device, so be it. I use my picture for LinkedIn but my avatar for all other activity on the Internet.

Back in the Middle Ages, your avatar would have been your heraldric emblem, which you would put on your shield so that others would recognize you, as you using your uncovered face as a recognition device would have been a very bad idea on a battlefield where every single sharp object would have an affinity for your face :)

The advantage of using an avatar is that your avatar doesn't need to change over the years as time catches up to you :) Whereas those who use a photo of their faces would have to update it every five to ten years - on every profile that they put out. Look at it this way, if your face got rearranged in an auto accident, you'd have to update your photos from a "before the event" photo to an "after the event" photo :)

On the other hand, if you are young, good looking and physically fit, why not flaunt it? You are always free to switch to an avatar as you feel the years adding up:)

Comment: What does "young, good looking and physically fit" have to do with it?  OP is talking about a professional site, not a dating site.  I am not young and I am average looking, are you saying I should not use a photo?

Comment: @cdkMoose You do whatever you want and whatever suits you. What I did was lay out the rationale behind my answer including options and the trade offs. At the end of the day, whatever decision you make about yourself is yours to make and it's certainly none of my concern. There are plenty of average looking, excellent character actors around. And they don't seem shy around the camera. The reason I say "if you are young, good looking and fit, it's OK to flaunt it" is that once upon a time, I was young, good looking and fit :) And I regret that I did not flaunt it when I had the chance :)

Answer (score 6):

I also use an avatar.

[image: Avatar]

As a developer, in my experience this has not hurt my career (I have a thing for putting my image up in public). The HR people at work don't particularly like it but I don't particularly want my image spread across the internet so hard cheese.

One young person in a suit seems particularly indistinguishable from another young person in a suit. A unique avatar servers as a form of signature and helps link your different sites together.

Comment: I'm guessing you wouldn't want to work for anyone who was too put-off by your avatar.

Comment: @JeffO May I ask what that comment is supposed to mean?

Comment: @JeffO: I have been using that avatar for about 8 years now. In that time I have worked for Amazon/Microsoft/Moz and had offers from Google/Facebook (and handful of smaller companies). Only one company (in two cycles of looking for work) has rejected me (non have not asked me in for interview). So I don't think it has put anybody off. But the likely hood of them being put off by my avatar or a picture of me in a suit? I am not sure if that would make a difference. But I am a programmer not a front-end sales man. I get my job based on my performance at interview not because of a silly picture.

Comment: PS. I am not slating `front-end sales men/women` in any way. I am presume they also get their jobs in the same way.

Comment: @Sprottenwels - I am totally in favor of objective hiring practices that focus on the job requirements. Unfortunately, I've been exposed to corporations that have sent contract programmers home for wearing sneakers to work. Wouldn't a company with a business suit requirement for programmers be a "red flag" for you as well?

Answer (score 5):

My answer would be to use a good photo in the Profile Photo, but take advantage of other LinkedIn features to display your image as if it were a logo.

Your abstract photo is essentially a logo, and a blank or a logo in a Profile Photo might strike me as quirky or lazy or other not-good things. It's remotely possible, if you were marketing yourself as an artist, that I might be impressed by your artistic skill and creativity -- it becomes "professional" because its an artifact of your profession -- but you're not marketing yourself that way so it wouldn't cross my mind.

You can have it both ways: a personalizing photo where it's expected and your brand/logo where it makes sense and enhances your brand. It's not an either-or decision.

Answer (score 0):

Use the social network to your benefit. LinkedIn is about connecting and finding job opportunities. Your outcome depends on your input. Whatever benefit you'll see from LinkedIn depends on your profile description, photo and the quality of your comments.

I used to have a professional photo with business-like description and received professional job offers. Then I started tech blogging and teaching online and changed my profile to be more accessible, with the same photo as I have here.

The job offers stopped coming and got cooperation offers from founders and startups instead and the number of my followers grew dramatically, people who found my blog connected on LinkedIn, too.

So LinkedIn is a tool and you can adjust it to your needs and goals. If you need a new job, you'd better give the signals to recruiters with a polished profile.

An easy thing is to have an open mind, try both and see what LinkedIn has to offer.

Answer (score -8):

The people who are using avatars in a professional network like LinkedIn are simply nobbies.
A recruiter must know whit who he's talking before meet him or her.
There are several points about using avatars like not having self-confidence, ugliness, no respect...etc.
So, you can use your avatars in gaming plateformes or other, but nooo in a professionnal network.

Comment: What utter nonsense. There's an argument about appearing professional etc, but 'A recruiter must know whit who he's talking before meet him or her. ' is just complete guff. LinkedIn is still a baby in recruitment terms, and MANY MANY people (including highly skilled, confident, sought after people) do not have LinkedIN profiles or have bare bones ones with no picture. Any recruiter taking LinkedIn pictures seriously is putting themselves at a huge disadvantage and will quickly lose out. Incidentally, I know somebody who recently sold a company for many millions with an avatar similar to OPs

Comment: Plenty of people do not have linkedIn profile pictures. It's not necessary, do you put a selfie on your resume? Appearance should not be considered when it comes to recruitment, unless you're talking professionalism which should not be judged until you come in for an interview.