# Could my name be misinterpreted?

Tags: resume, job-search

I'm starting my job hunt now and I've realized I might have a problem on my hands. In my country my name is strictly given to males. But in the UK (where I'm searching) my name is mostly given to females.

Could this be a problem? Should I address this potential source of confusion on my CV/cover letter? As far as I know putting your gender or photo on your CV is not standard practise (and takes away precious space you have).

Granted any prospective employer would figure out that I'm a male after a quick google search for my name, but still ... I feel I should address this. Or am I making a fuss out of non-issue?

Comment: As a side note, placing a nice photo into a resume would be a great advantage. It makes things more "human". Just make it a floating box hanging in top-right or top-left corner near your name, objective positions, and keywords.

Comment: @bytebuster - whilst this may be good practice for a resume, in the UK (for a CV) this is really bad practice and should be avoided!

Comment: @Dibstar It's interesting, can you elaborate a bit? Is it just an unwritten rule of convenience, or some formal regulation?

Comment: @bytebuster it is mainly because your appearance shouldn't be an issue when it comes to you getting a job - you may look too young / old (and your experience should be what counts)

Comment: @Dibstar I found [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7019/will-putting-my-picture-on-my-resume-help-me-get-the-job-easier-while-im-not-cl), and it seems that you are very right, especially as per UK, thanks. **OP, for your attention**.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to deal with a gender specific name in a foriegn culture but not really about navigating the workplace.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The only times this would ever be an issue are for roles in which sex is a genuine occupational qualification, such as working in a women's toilets / performing bodily searches etc.

Assuming that the roles you are going for do not involve any such duties, any employer would be breaching the law if they discriminated against you based on your perceived gender.

Comment: I'm looking for a job in IT, so gender is not relevant.

Comment: @GuyGuy in that case I wouldn't worry!

Comment: Working in womens toilets is *not* a valid reason for sex discrimination (male cleaning attendants are used all the time in the UK for this), performing bodily searches is also unlikely to be as typically both males and females would need to be searched.

Comment: In the US anyway, the TSA will only allow agents to perform pat-downs (body searches) on individuals who are the same gender. IOW, a male agent can't perform a search on a female traveler.

Comment: @Michael. If both males and females need to be searched, and if the gender of the agent must match that of the person being searched, both male and female agents need to be hired. If the male agent retires, a new male agent must be hired. And the employer can, and should, advertise for male applicants only.

Comment: @Michael On the women's restrooms, at least, the same is true in the US.  In my building, they just knock and make sure there's no one in there before they enter.

Comment: @TRiG I cannot imagine what a hassle for the TSA an "out" intersex passenger may create..  (o_0)

Comment: @Izkata. I imagine the TSA is only vaguely aware that such people exist. And as for trans, genderqueer, agender people and everyone else ....

Answer (score 23):

Why not just add "Mr. **__ *_*_**" to your CV and other messages? That will clear it unambiguously. Generally it's women that get discriminated, so you should be fine with disclosing your gender, even if it is not necessary.

Comment: This. To assume that there is no discrimination against women would be very naive.

Comment: -1 "Generally it's women that get discriminated" - I would contest this - I have seen positive discrimination used to discriminate against men (and vice versa)

Comment: @Dibstar: Anecdotal example doesn't change the general state of the world. http://whatever.scalzi.com/2012/05/15/straight-white-male-the-lowest-difficulty-setting-there-is/

Comment: @pdr: Hehe, thanks for that link, it really made my day. Especially reading some of the comments.

Comment: +1 for the first two sentences providing a way to solve the OPs concern, -1 for the assumption baked into the third (regardless of it's level of correctness).

Comment: Everyone should read the article @pdr linked to, as well as the two followup articles.

Comment: I loved the link.

Answer (score 4):

It's a non-issue - It would be illegal in the UK to differentiate between males and females for any job role.

I've interviewed people with "traditional female or male" names and been surprised when walking into the interview room but it's never been a problem.

Comment: I know it's illegal ... but still :) Maybe you're right and I'm over-thinking this whole thing :)

Comment: To be honest, in IT, being perceived as female might help you get an interview :)

Comment: lol, you might be right :)

Comment: @michael, I am female and in IT and it is harder many places to get an interview if you are female. There are too many people who think women cannot program. This used to annoy me and then I realized that I wouldn't want to work for them anyway and that there are plenty of places happy to hire me.

Comment: Ok - fair enough, I'm not :) but I know in our company, we strive to have a balanced workforce and it's incredibly difficult to find female programmers (we wouldn't hire someone because they were female but it certainly wouldn't hurt their chances).

Comment: "Illegal" and "never happens" are not the same.

Comment: That is true but I'd question if you'd want to work for a company that took such an outdated and sexist approach to their workforce - probably getting off topic now.

Comment: You probably do not work for an overtly outdated and sexist company, but I'd bet a ton of dollars you work for a covertly outdated and sexist company.  The issue remains.  We have a long ways to go.  Just scan the top 1,000 companies and analyze who are in the top roles.

Comment: @Michael Regarding "outdated and sexist approach to their workforce". One sexist interviewer (deliberate or not) does not determine the attitude of the business. It is illegal in the UK, but it still happens.

Answer (score 4):

Notwithstanding laws and how far we have come over the past fifty years or so, we are still a very biased group, just in a much more covert way.  Hiring practices are still plagued with assumptions that are tied to from which group an individual comes--race, sex, religion, age, etc.  We are still tied to stereotypes and the mostly false predictions that are derived from them.

You asking this question exposes what I am writing.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question

Comment: Oh...the OP asked if it could be a problem.  I was trying to address that it could very well be a problem.  I did not offer any answer on how to mitigate it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would say just include it in the header of your CV, it won't take up much space at.

Regardless of the fact that there are laws to protect against discrimination, people do make judgements based on your gender and I see no issue with clearing up ambiguity.

Comment: Why add anything onto the CV that can **only** be used against you? I would advise very strongly against this

Comment: Why do you think it would be used against him?

Comment: Because we are biased people and we discriminate all the time, no matter the laws.  It is disgusting and it's great we're headed in the right direction, but don't fool yourselves.  We have a long long way to to.

Comment: Absolutely, but I think we agree that if there is discrimination based on names it is more than likely going to be towards females (as HLGEM points out in her experience in another comment). The person asking is male with a female sounding name, I'd say it would be to his benefit to make this distinction and given that situation, i.e. where there is ambiguity then it wouldn't seem unusual.

Comment: Yes, I agree--sadly.

Comment: -1: I would find it very strange to see gender mentioned in a CV.

Comment: Recruitment agencies in the UK often remove personally identifiable information from CVs before sending them to employers, gender, age/DoB, address, nationality, disabilities, even name. Sometimes they do a complete once over on your CV meaning the finished product is not close to what you submitted. I've had candidates turn up with a copy of their CV that doesn't even closely resemble what the agent submitted.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know putting your gender or photo on your CV is not standard practise

Actually I don't think so. In the European CV standard template, both the Photo and personal data (sex included under the *Gender* entry) are taken into account.

I'd include both of them, without making the Photo two big so that it doesn't take too much space. If you must choose though, exclude the Gender entry, because the photo will not only give that information but it will also help them see who you are in a different way and help establish a better relation from the start.

Comment: [This page says otherwise](http://www.prospects.ac.uk/writing_a_cv.htm) - "As a rule, do not include information relating to your age, sex, nationality, marital status or health." - both age and gender can be guessed from a photo.

Comment: @alroc In the Europass template, which is provided by the European Commission, they are included by default. Perhaps in UK they prefer not to, I am not aware of that...

Comment: Added clarification to tend towards photo. :)