# Should I add my photo to CV if I get benefit from it?

Tags: resume

I think everyone will agree with this statement: "A picture is worth a thousand words". It should also be applied to CV too. Searching on the internet, I find many advices tell me to avoid this, most of them are opinions. I don't understand this. The only one article I found which encourage you to adding photo in CV is from [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/robasghar/2013/07/22/no-photo-on-your-resume-and-other-career-advice-you-should-question/).

An example of a CV with photo: [image]

---

This is [a question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7019/will-putting-my-picture-on-my-resume-help-me-get-the-job-easier-while-im-not-cl) that also ask the same thing, and I notice that I have a slightly different question.
The main reason to stay away from putting photo into CV is discrimination. However my country doesn't have that law, and in fact I have benefit from this.

> Attractive males received a 19.9% callback rate, almost 50% higher
>   than the 13.7% response for plain men and more than twice the 9.2%
>   response to those with no photo.

I am not an attractive one, I have acne. But many of my friends say that I have feature that if I use Photoshop, I will have a nice-looking. So sorry if you feel I'm over confident.

**If you have many chances to apply CVs with photos, does adding photo make your CVs have more chance to be accepted?**

Comment: Unless the job requires you to be presentable and look a certain way (model, tv personality, spokes person), I see those "1000 words" as nothing but a distraction and could do more harm than good. Do you really want a job where the manager picked you because you're good looking?

Comment: Hi Ooker, there are other answers on that question which don't talk about discrimination, which seem like they apply to your case. Would you mind clarifying a bit further? Sorry if I'm just missing it, but I'm still not quite sure I understand your question. It seems like, if you know you'd benefit, you should just do it...

Comment: [cont'd] I'll drop a link in [chat] so more people see this. [Users with 3000+ reputation can vote to reopen](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) and anyone else can [work with you to get this reopened](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) via more clarifying comments and suggested edits. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @jmort253, I do read the answers in that question, and in fact, the quote I have is copied from [GuyM](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/7026)'s answer. I don't know where to improve this, can you show me where you feel unclear? I still think that I'll get benefit, but if adding photo make the CV looks unprofessional, may it will have more chance to be rejected.

Comment: Hi Ooker, I think what's not clear is the actual question. "Should I add my photo to my CV if it benefits me?" The obvious answer to that is "Yes, if it benefits you, why would you not do it."  That's the question in the title, which differs from the question hiding in the middle of the body. I usually suggest folks make the title match what's in the body, and then also move the question to the bottom so it's clear what answerers should be focusing on. Lastly, the question should be something we can answer with facts, references, and experience, not unsubstantiated opinion.

Comment: [cont'd] - I'd suggest starting by making it more clear what the actual question is in Q&A format. I've given this a head start for you; see the [revision history](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/33639/revisions). Hope this helps.

Comment: @jmort253: thank you so much for spending time helping me. I just think the problem should be: _If generally paper with photo are more attractive, and if I need not to worry about discrimination issue, still adding photo to CV makes it unprofessional?_ Do you think I need to write a new question?

Comment: Hi Ooker, you should jump into [chat] so we keep the comments from getting too large.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting a picture on your cv is almost always a bad thing. First it wastes space that can be better used to sell your skills. CVs should never exceed 2 pages and if you put a picture there , you have less room for describing your skills.

Second, it appears naive as if you don't understand how things are done. Being thought of as naive is rarely a good thing when trying to imporess someone enought to schedule an interview.

Third, it could very well make it easy for someone to screen you out based on appearance. So if you are not model-beautifiul, it doesn't work in your favor to have a picture. It is a known problem that short people, overweight people, older people, people of color, and unattractive people are judged more harshly in interviews. If you put the picture out there before the interview, you may get judged that way long before it gets to the interview and you have lost your chance to overcome that by selling yourself with your enthusiasm and technical ability. If you did choose to put a picture in, then it had better be of the highest qualty and that means hiring a really good professional photographer which can be costly.

Fourth, what would you gain from it?  Yes a picture is worth a thousand words but how would having a picture help sell you to a potential employer? Are you selling your looks or your skills? A picture tells me nothing about your skills. Might as well put a picture of a cute puppy there, it would have as much positive impact for you.

It is true there are some jobs where a photo would be expected. Jobs where your looks are a large part of what you are selling such as acting or modeling.

Comment: @ooker, what you added doesn't change my answer.  Unless you are in a profession like acting, then it looks unprofessional and silly. Maybe you think you are attractive enough it would help, but really attractiveness is in the eye of the beholder and people doing hiring are not impressed by tricks substituting for content. I would strongly recommend that you not put a picture on your resume. Yes attractive people do have an easier time getting hired. But none of the very attractive people I know have a picture on their resume because it is very unprofessional for most professions.

Answer (score 8):

Well the example is of someone who is experienced in print media/design and photography, so it probably makes sense in this case, but generally no.

Main reason - most countries have laws against discrimination for age/race/religious reasons.  For this reason you tend not to put any of these items on a CV (unless it's a benefit, e.g. in a religious school etc).   You can do the same thing with a photo (a picture worth a thousand words etc).

By having a picture, you can show all the things you didn't mention, and allow the potential employer to rule you out without actually talking to you.

If you want a photo, put it on your LinkedIn profile, and put a link on your CV, the reader is more likely to be interested in you before they follow it, so less likely to rule you straight out.

Comment: If you are going for a job in print|media, then it makes sense to include your photo - assuming that it is the norm in your industry to send CVs with your photo in it. If including the photo is not the norm in your industry, then replace your photo with some creative, maybe custom, avatar.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere It really depends on the industry. As a grad student, I used to moonlight with a theater director as his assistant. All of the actors' and actresses' resumes we reviewed had their photos on them. We rejected the few resumes that didn't include photos out of hand. Unfortunately, except for those who have major parts, everybody else is a stock player. If a theater director is looking for a combat veteran, someone who looks like a teenage slacker won't do. Acting is a business where if you play the minor parts, your looks are your talent :)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere And in case you are wondering what's an engineering school grad student from Columbia doing moonlighting off-off Broadway as a theater director's assistant, the one-word answer: actresses :)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Most American HR's frown on candidates including their photos on their resumes - That's because they want to be color blind, ethnic blind in their hiring and they don't want to prejudge on looks. I don't know what the law and custom are in Sweden, both in general and the OP's industry. If the OP's industry frown on candidates' photos, I suggested putting an avatar instead - The resume is a pretty good layout and I'd hate to see it go to waste :) On the other hand, this layout is going to be murder on the automated word parsers :)

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan For actors, their appearance is part of what they are selling, so of course they want folks to see that. Maybe that applies for jobs that involve a lot of public PR. For most of the rest of us, the photo either isn't going to help or is going to raise more issues than it resolves.

Answer (score 6):

As someone who has done his bit of recruiting in the past (for IT developers and similar), I would say that generally the answer is no. The number of CVs I've read that have had photos on them .. well, they don't inspire confidence in the individual especially when the vast majority of other CVs are just plain text. Pictures slapped on top next to the candidate name looks like they're either trying to "stand out", are narcissistic, or are overly fond of social media styles! (and invariable the photo that's added looks like it was taken in a passport booth with the typical fixed pose and awkward grin)

That said, for a design job, I look at your CV and think that would be a wonderful CV to receive. I think that would be a good CV to receive even for a technical development job too, the trick is (as with everything) to make it look like it is supposed to be there.